# How to add buttons from code to a tabpage?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a private void AddButtons() that I’m trying to add to tabPage1 only when the form is loaded.

I’ve tried:

```
   public frmMain()
    {
        TabControl tabControl = new TabControl();
        if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabPage1)
        {
            AddButtons();
        }
    }
  private void tabControl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl.TabPages[1])
        {
            AddButtons();
        }
    }

    private void tabControl_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl.SelectedTab == tabControl.TabPages[1])
        {
            AddButtons();
        }
    }
   private void tabControl_Selected(object sender, TabControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.TabPage == tabPage1)
        {
            AddButtons();
        }
    }
```

The first one load the buttons on all tabs. the next 3 did not load anything.

Comment: Can we see the code to `AddButtons`?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue to check is that arrays are zero-based in C#. This means that *tabPage1* is probably `tabControl.TabPages[0]`, instead of what you tried.

In order to properly answer your question, we should be able to see the code of *form1.AddButtons()*. It is interesting that adds buttons to all tab pages. Are you sure about this. If you made the same mistake as above, you would see the buttons in the second tab page.

**Edited**: `Controls.Add(pnlButtons);` -> With this statement, you are adding the panel with the buttons to the form, not to the *tabPage1*.

**Edited**: since nothing seems to work, I've created a project like yours myself.

First of all, I created a **MainWindow**.

```
public class MainWindow: Form {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Build();
    }

    TabControl BuildTabs()
    {
        this.Tabs = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        this.Tabs.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, evt) => this.OnTabChanged();
        this.Tabs.TabPages.Add( new TabPage{ Text = "Tab1" } );
        this.Tabs.TabPages.Add( new TabPage{ Text = "Tab2" } );

        return this.Tabs;
    }

    void Build()
    {
        this.MinimumSize = new Size( 580, 460 );
        this.Text = "Programmatic creation";
        this.Controls.Add( this.BuildTabs() );
    }

    public TabControl Tabs {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

The **MainWindow**.*AddButtons()* method is exactly the same you wrote, I did not want to change anything (except the line remarked above). Take into account that, however, you can achieve the same result with a **TableLayoutPanel** without absolute positioning (absolute positioning is undesirable since it won't work with different window sizes).

So, now, you only need the event handlers:

```
    void AddButtons()
    {
        // many things
    }

    void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Button clicked!" );
    }

    void OnTabChanged()
    {
        if ( this.Tabs.SelectedIndex == 1 ) {
            this.AddButtons();
        }
    }
```

Everything works as expected. I suspect you have a lot of tiny errors that prevent your project from working.

The whole code is below:

```
public class MainWindow: Form {
    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.Build();
    }

    void AddButtons()
    {
        var pnlButtons = new Panel();
        pnlButtons.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pnlButtons.Location = new Point(370, 59);
        pnlButtons.BackColor = Color.White;

        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;
        // assign number of buttons = 27
        var btnArray = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[27];

        // Create (27) Buttons:
        int n = 0;
        while (n < 27)
        {
            btnArray[n] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            btnArray[n].Tag = n + 1; // Tag of button
            btnArray[n].Width = 28; // Width of button
            btnArray[n].Height = 24; // Height of button

            // Location of button:
            btnArray[n].Left = xPos;
            btnArray[n].Top = yPos;
            // Add buttons to a Panel:
            //To change Panel Buttons from Vertical to Horizontal move the multiplier from pnlButtons.Height to pnlButtons.Width
            pnlButtons.Height = btnArray[n].Height * 27;
            pnlButtons.Width = btnArray[n].Width;
            pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnArray[n]); // Let panel hold the Buttons
            yPos = yPos + btnArray[n].Height; //For Vertical buttons
            //xPos = xPos + btnArray[n].Width; // For Horizontal buttons

            // Write English Character:

            char[] Alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 
            'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '*'};
            btnArray[n].Text = Alphabet[n].ToString();
            this.Tabs.TabPages[ 1 ].Controls.Add(pnlButtons);

            // the Event of click Button
            btnArray[n].Click += (o, evt) => this.OnButtonClicked();
            n++;
        }
    }

    TabControl BuildTabs()
    {
        this.Tabs = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        this.Tabs.SelectedIndexChanged += (o, evt) => this.OnTabChanged();
        this.Tabs.TabPages.Add( new TabPage{ Text = "Tab1" } );
        this.Tabs.TabPages.Add( new TabPage{ Text = "Tab2" } );

        return this.Tabs;
    }

    void Build()
    {
        this.MinimumSize = new Size( 580, 460 );
        this.Text = "Programmatic creation";
        this.Controls.Add( this.BuildTabs() );
    }

    void OnButtonClicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Button clicked!" );
    }

    void OnTabChanged()
    {
        if ( this.Tabs.SelectedIndex == 1 ) {
            this.AddButtons();
        }
    }

    public TabControl Tabs {
        get; private set;
    }
}
```

I finally decided to modify your *AddButtons()*, so it also works better:

```
    void AddButtons()
    {
        TabPage tabPage1 = this.Tabs.TabPages[ 1 ];

        if ( tabPage1.Controls.Count == 0 ) {
            var pnlButtons = new TableLayoutPanel();
            pnlButtons.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            pnlButtons.AutoScroll = true;

            // assign number of buttons = 27
            var btnArray = new Button[27];

            // Create (27) Buttons:
            int n = 0;
            while( n < 26 ) {
                btnArray[n] = new Button{ Tag = n + 1 };

                // Add buttons to a Panel:
                //To change Panel Buttons from Vertical to Horizontal move the multiplier from pnlButtons.Height to pnlButtons.Width
                pnlButtons.Controls.Add( btnArray[n] ); // Let panel hold the Buttons

                // Write English Character:
                btnArray[n].Text = char.ToString( (char) ( 'a' + n ) );

                // the Event of click Button
                btnArray[n].Click += (o, evt) => this.OnButtonClicked();

                ++n;
            }

            btnArray[n] = new Button {  Tag = n + 1 };
            btnArray[n].Text = char.ToString( '*' );
            pnlButtons.Controls.Add( btnArray[n] );
            tabPage1.Controls.Add( pnlButtons );
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did know about the tab pages starting with 0, but at that point in the code I was just trying to get the buttons to show.

Comment: `Controls.Add(pnlButtons);` -> With this statement, you are adding the panel with the buttons to the form, not to the *tabPage1*.

Comment: I’ve tired changing that statement to tabPage1.Controls.Add(pnlButtons);. No buttons showed on any tab.  Also tired tabControl.Controls.Add(pnlButtons); with that I get ‘only tab pages can be added to TabControls’. 
I originally created this form without tabs, but decided to add more items which called for the addition of the tabs.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you. I’ve been working trying to combine your code with mine. It’s working with only some clean up and minor changes to due. 
Some changes that I did with your code was Tabs.TabPages[1].Controls.Add(pnlButtons) to Tabs.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(pnlButtons) this of course put the buttons on tabpage1 but only after clicking on tabpage2 and then back. That required adding AddButtons() to Public MainWindow(), now everything worked.

Comment: I tried your AddButtons() but it was not as flexible as the code I have. By docking full you put the buttons at position 0, 0 and the new point (370, 59) did nothing. With the code I use x & yPos is what determines the size of the panel, as you add or subtract buttons or change the height and width of the buttons the panel changes. Then to change the buttons from vertical to horizontal you multiply the height or width by the number of buttons you have and then use the yPos or xPos option.

Comment: I know there are other ways to fill the buttons ASCII  and what you showed. Neither would give me the asterisk at the end. The button panel controls a data grid viewer, by clicking on a letter the grid reloads with only the records that start with that letter. Clicking on the asterisk reloads the grid with all records.

Comment: @VinVin, if you need a, say, index of buttons, then create a panel such as mine docked at the left, then another panel with dock fill which I suppose would show the data. As I said, absolute positioning is always a bad idea.

Comment: @VinVin, your `AddButtons()` was not more flexible, it had many flaws such as code repeated. As you can see in my (modified) answer, you can get a '*' button if you need it easily.

Comment: If you feel this answer has helped you, then please consider marking it as the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: Ballasarg thank you for your help. My tab form is working as planned. Your change for loading the button text I’ll add to mine. The problems that I have with the rest of your revised code are: 1 no control of the width or height of the buttons, 2 how would change the button layout from vertical to horizontal. Also for some reason your code leaves a gap between each button, requiring a larger form to accommodate them. The code I use each button is stacked one on top of or next to the other.

Comment: I don’t understand why ‘absolute positioning is always a bad idea’. My form is a fixed size so the location of the buttons should not change. My form has the datagridview on the left with the buttons next than a panel with 8 textboxs that get filled from a click on the grid cell.

Comment: Absolute positioning means that what looks beautiful today will look awful tomorrow when the window results to be bigger or smaller due to, for example, resolution change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a copy of the AddButtons. I got this years ago for a VB.Net program I was working on and just converted it for my first try in C#. The button click at the end just changes a SQL select statement for filling the DataGridView.

```
     private void AddButtons()
    {
        Panel pnlButtons = new Panel();
        pnlButtons.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(370, 59);
        pnlButtons.BackColor = Color.White;

        int xPos = 0;
        int yPos = 0;
        // assign number of buttons = 27
        btnArray = new System.Windows.Forms.Button[27];
        // Create (27) Buttons:
        for (int i = 0; i < 27; i++)
        {
            // Initialize one variable
            btnArray[i] = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        }
        int n = 0;
        while (n < 27)
        {
            btnArray[n].Tag = n + 1; // Tag of button
            btnArray[n].Width = 28; // Width of button
            btnArray[n].Height = 24; // Height of button

            // Location of button:
            btnArray[n].Left = xPos;
            btnArray[n].Top = yPos;
            // Add buttons to a Panel:
            //To change Panel Buttons from Vertical to Horizontal move the multiplier from pnlButtons.Height to pnlButtons.Width
            pnlButtons.Height = btnArray[n].Height * 27;
            pnlButtons.Width = btnArray[n].Width;
            pnlButtons.Controls.Add(btnArray[n]); // Let panel hold the Buttons
            yPos = yPos + btnArray[n].Height; //For Vertical buttons
            //xPos = xPos + btnArray[n].Width; // For Horizontal buttons

            // Write English Character:

            char[] Alphabet = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 
            'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 
            'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '*'};
            btnArray[n].Text = Alphabet[n].ToString();
            Controls.Add(pnlButtons);
            // the Event of click Button
            btnArray[n].Click += new System.EventHandler(ClickButton);
            n++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: fwiw... that piece of code should be added to your opening question.

Comment: I did not think that code was the cause. It was used on the same form without tabs with no problems.